# PhpStorm: Class 'PhpUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found (composer / autoload)

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I've got a problem with PhpStorm, composer and PHPUnit.

- Windows 8.1 Pro (64 bit)
- PhpStorm is up to date: 2018.2.2
- Tried different PHP interpreters like XAMPP and a clean PHP for win
- PHPUnit is required by composer with: `"phpunit/phpunit": "^7.3.3"`.
- PHPUnit is successfully installed via composer to the vendor directory as well.
- PHPUnit is recognized from PhpStorm:

[image]

My test class extends the `PhpUnit\Framework\TestCase` class and when you run the test, the following happens:

[image]

First it seems like PhpStorm loads the old PHPUnit (3.7.21) from XAMPP's PHP and not the recognized PHPUnit (7.3.3) as setup in the PhpStorm settings / installed to the vendor folder.

But I don't think so.

I think PhpStorm tries to load the `PhpUnit\Framework\TestCase` class by the autoloader, but I don't know why it doesn't find the PHPUnit...

Thanks in advance!

---

The whole project could be minimized to this simple test class:

[image]

The `composer.json` looks like the following:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Flo\\Newsletter\\": "src/"
  }
},
"require": {
  "php": "^7.1"
},
"require-dev": {
  "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.3.3"
}
```

Comment: Please note that PhpStorm doesn't load anything. It just forms a command that is executed later. Please check what would `C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:/Users/flb/dev/composer/newsletter/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --version` return. If it's 7.3.3, then there's a problem in the code, and we need the project to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Eugene Morozov, I've just edited the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are case-sensitive. Please change `PhpUnit` to `PHPUnit` in the import.

Although PhpStorm could really detect that. Here's a feature request for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38140

Comment: Oh my! `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;` solves the problem! I don't know why it was `PhpUnit`... I always use PhpStorm's suggests... Thanks man.